# How do I create a symbolic link in Mac OSX?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, bash, terminal, alias

I have a .sh file that I need to create a symbolic link. I would like to be able to access the file using the Terminal.

The command I use is:

```
ln -s /path/roo.sh /usr/bin/roo
```

But when I type `roo`, it says command not found. If I type `/path/roo.sh`, it works. Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: Can you verify that `/usr/bin/roo` exists?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you did should work. Troubleshooting:

1. Are you under root? Did `ln` command actually succeed? Verify with `ls -l /usr/bin/roo` which should list the newly created link. If the link is not there, add "sudo " before `ln` to execute it as root (sudo will prompt for root's password):

   > **sudo** ln -s /path/roo.sh /usr/bin/roo
2. Sometimes bash remembers where a certain executable is, and will not search in other locations. Enter `hash -r` to make it forget, and then try `roo` again.
3. "/usr/bin" should definitely be in your PATH, but it won't hurt to verify: `echo $PATH` should include "/usr/bin"

Comment: What I did wrong was that I use the current directory as the path ./folder1/folder2/roo.sh and when i type ls -l /usr/bin/roo, it shows that error. Thanks for that good tip haimg :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the command `alias roo="/usr/bin/roo"`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to use roo as a command ou might want to look at the alias command.

In this case you would do :

```
alias roo="path to roo"
```

to call it you will just need to do `roo`

For example

```
alias test="ruby /Users/user/Desktop/test.rb"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the symlink is did not created, as you can do this only with sudo from the terminal.
Please check /usr/bin/roo is exists.

If exists, please try `echo ${PATH}` command, it shows you the folders where the shell search you command. If it does not contains /usr/bin, then try to fix it with adding `export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/bin"` into your ~/.profile

Answer (score 0):

My `echo $PATH` showed me that /usr/local/bin/ was also in my path, so I just used /usr/local/bin/roo as my link target.

```
ln -s /path/roo.sh /usr/local/bin/roo
```

Answer (score -1):

If exists, please try echo ${PATH} command, it shows you the folders where the shell search you command. If it does not contains /usr/bin, then try to fix it with adding export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/bin" into your ~/.profile

Comment: -1. The accepted answer which was posted 9 years ago already contains this tip, and more.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.